# Matching Property on Heterogenous Data using Deep Learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

The issue I face is that I want to match properties (houses/apartments etc) that are similar to each other (e.g. longitude and latitude (numerical), bedrooms (numerical), district (categorial), condition (categorical) etc.) using deep learning. The data is heterogenous because we mix numerical and categorical data and the problem is unsupervised because we don’t use any labels.

My goal is to get a measure for how similar properties are so I can find the top matches for each target property. I could use KNN, but I want to use something that allows me to find embeddings and that uses deep learning.

I suppose I could determine a mixed distance measure such as the Gower Distance as the loss function, but how would I go about setting up a model that determines the, say, the top 10 matches for each target property in my sample?

Any help or points to similar problem sets (Kaggle, notebooks, github) would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want an unsupervised approach, you could try using an auto-encoder. I have found Variational Auto-Encoders (VAEs) to be pretty good for other problems. The learned embedding should respect distance in the input space to some extent, but you might need to modify the loss function slightly if you want examples to be separated in a specific way.

To get the top k, you can just encode each example, compute a distance matrix and take the top k in each row (or col).

I have an implementation of VAEs (and others) in Pytorch: [here](https://github.com/BenedictWilkinsAI/pyworld-rl) for your reference, obviously you will need a different  network architecture to handle the categorical aspects etc.

Hope this helps!